# Rails - find by with two fields using OR instead of AND?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am familiar with doing a find on two fields:

```
user = User.find_by_username_and_email(params[:username], params[:email])
```

However, I would like to retrieve one record where the username OR email equals the same field. Something like:

```
user = User.find_by_username_or_email(params[:text])
```

Which I know doesn't work. Is this possible? Any help is a appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `.where` :

```
user = User.where('username = ? or email = ?', params[:text], params[:text]).first
```

Comment: It works ... I had a feeling I needed to use 'where'. Thanks!

Comment: @Drew I'd likely wrap this up into a method, though that doesn't change the implementation detail.

Answer (score 7):

Just to expand on the answer by @xdazz, you can use the following syntax to allow searching any number of fields by the same value without having to repeat the value:

```
user = User.where('username = :text or email = :text', :text => params[:text]).first
```

Very useful when you come to search postal address fields, for example.

[2.2.1 Placeholder Conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions)

Comment: This reads better than the correct answer